# Execute a Jquery plugin after AngularJS has been rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I receive an object collection via Ajax:

```
// Var available in the template
this.list = [];

// This function refresh the list
var self = this;
this.refreshList = function () {
  ChannelService.get({}, function (result) {
    self.list = result.objects;
  });
};

// Initial refresh of the list
this.refreshList();
```

This collection is used to populate a select:

```
<option ng-repeat="channel in ChanListCtrl.list" value="channel.id">
    {{ channel.description }}
</option>
```

Problem: After the rendering of the view, I would like to use a jQuery plugin called "Multiselect" to improve the look&feel of my select.

The plugin is used like this:

```
element.multiSelect()
```

I tried this solution: [AngularJS and jQuery plugin after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635405/angularjs-and-jquery-plugin-after-render)

This widget is correctly displayed but AngularJS doesn't replace the variables ({{ channel.description }})

I tried to broadcast an event when the Ajax is done but it doesn't work... I also tried to call an update function with ng-init on my html tag but without success.

Here is a plunker to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/EMOjy1TbSkQvCjbxZlFX?p=preview

Comment: My guess is that after calling jQuery plugin, you need to tell angular to do it's job again. For that you need $compile service, $compile(element)($scope), see docs for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Also, I do suggest you use a directive to improve the look and feel of your select boxes. It will save you a lot of trouble: http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/

Comment: @jValdron I already saw this directive but it doesn't use ng-model and the look&feel is not what I'm looking for. Rasalom: Could you please be more explicit ? I don't see how I could use $compile to solve my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you create an example in jsfiddle/plnkr/smth_else so I could edit code there.

Comment: It's done, I edited my first post. Thx

Comment: I'd suggest using answer from @jValdron, because using $compile caused another problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd watch the `list` variable for any changes, and when a change is detected, I'd call the `refresh` method from the multiselect plugin.

In your controller:

```
// Initialize the multiselect before anything else.
$('#channels').multiSelect();

// Add a watch on the list. Notice this uses the $timeout
// service, so you'll have to add that to your controller.
$scope.$watch('list', function(){
  $timeout(function(){
    $('#channels').multiSelect('refresh');
  });
});
```

Full Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FRpy2aEZUu9csUoKJYZO

Comment: Thx, it works even with the real Ajax call. But I would like to put the watch in an other controller. Is it possible ? Example : http://plnkr.co/edit/nWz3NWhsRoiReXtL0ZnB?p=preview

Comment: From your Plunker, it's possible to do as you're doing, and it'll work, but I don't think it's the "Angular way" ;)

Comment: Any improvements to suggest ? Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, and that'd fall under another question.